# phonegap rename file with moveTo

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

iam trying to rename a image file that was taken, but i get always in fail method with error.code = 1

```
function renameImage(imageURI) {  
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, renameFile, fail);
}
function renameFile(entry){
    var parent = entry.fullPath.substr(0, entry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    deleteFile(entry);
    entry.moveTo(parent, newFileName, setImageSrc, fail);
}
```

deleteFile works fine

parent is **file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera**

update:

```
var path = obj.src.substr(0, obj.src.lastIndexOf('/'));
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function() {}, function() { alert("requestFS");});
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path,  function(e) {
    path = e
    }, function() { alert("resolveFsURI path");});
```

resolveLocalFileSystemURI still exist with error: 1

edit:
 it shows the same reaction without deleteFile()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are calling moveTo with the parent being a path when it needs to be a DirectoryEntry.

Comment: i tried:

var p = entry.fullPath.substr(0, entry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
var directory = new DirectoryEntry({fullpath:p+'/test'});
//deleteFile(entry);
entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, setImageSrc, fail);

**and get error code 1**

Comment: This line:

    var directory = new DirectoryEntry({fullpath:p+'/test'});

may not give you a real directory entry. You may want to take the 'p+"/test"' and call window.resolveLocalFilesystemURI() to get a DirectoryEntry in the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

After some tries i use this:

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(i) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(i, function(e) {
            var p = e.fullPath.substr(0, e.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(p, function(dir) {
                e.moveTo(dir, newName, function(f) {
                    changedSomething = true;
                    var d = new Date();
                    obj.hide();
                    //alert(f.fullPath);
                    obj.attr('src', f.fullPath+'?i='+d.getMilliseconds());
                    obj.fadeIn(600);
                    e.remove(onEmptyLoader, onEmptyLoader);}, onErrorLoader);
            }, onErrorLoader);
        }, onErrorLoader);
    }, onErrorLoader, cameraOptions);
```

sorry for the late response i forgot this question :)